# How to create a new column based on a string formation of a different row in python pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, string-formatting

Lets say I have the following df:

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Food': ['Apple Cake', 'Orange Tomato', 'Brocolli Apple', 'Cake Orange', 'Tomato Apple']})
test


       Food
0   Apple Cake
1   Orange Tomato
2   Brocolli Apple
3   Cake Orange
4   Tomato Apple
```

And I want to create a new column that replaces the actual food with the type of food it is:

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'Food': ['Apple Cake', 'Orange Tomato', 'Brocolli Apple', 'Cake Orange', 'Tomato Apple'], 'Type' : ['Fruit Dessert', 'Fruit Veggie', 'Veggie Fruit', 'Dessert Fruit', 'Veggie Fruit']})
test1


       Food             Type
0   Apple Cake      Fruit Dessert
1   Orange Tomato   Fruit Veggie
2   Brocolli Apple  Veggie Fruit
3   Cake Orange     Dessert Fruit
4   Tomato Apple    Veggie Fruit
```

How would I go about this? would I make a dictionary of the following:

```
{'Fruit' : ['Apple', 'Orange'], 'Veggies': ['Brocolli', 'Tomato'], 'Dessert': 'Cake'}
```

And do something with that dictionary? I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: This is a broad question. You need to somehow store the mapping of categories with each item. But, this could be intricate too. Like, you would need to store case-insensitive items. You would need to have kind of a `fuzzy match` like `Aple` should also map to `Apple` and much more. You kind of need to provide more details.

Comment: The data I'm working with is all spelled correctly. I just want to map the values of one column and create a new column replacing the value with its category. Another example would be countries with continents etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in one pass... but you can do it in several passes:

```py
test = pd.DataFrame({'Food': ['Apple Cake', 'Orange Tomato', 'Brocolli Apple', 'Cake Orange', 'Tomato Apple']})

dict = {'Fruit' : [r'Apple', r'Orange'], 'Veggies': [r'Brocolli', r'Tomato'], 'Dessert': [r'Cake']}

test['Type'] = test['Food']
for k in dict.keys():
    test['Type'] = test['Type'].replace(regex=dict[k], value=k)

test
```

```
       Food             Type
0   Apple Cake      Fruit Dessert
1   Orange Tomato   Fruit Veggie
2   Brocolli Apple  Veggie Fruit
3   Cake Orange     Dessert Fruit
4   Tomato Apple    Veggie Fruit
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd do this is by:

- Invertnig the dictionary of lists, so that each value becomes a key, with its respective key as dictionary
- Splitting the strings, `stack`ing into a `pd.Series`, map with the obtained dictionary,  `groupby` the first level index and `join` back

---

```
d  = {'Fruit' :['Apple', 'Orange'], 'Veggies':['Brocolli', 'Tomato'], 'Dessert': 'Cake'}

d_inv = {i: k  for k,v in d.items() for i in (v if isinstance(v, list) else [v])}
# {'Apple': 'Fruit', 'Orange': 'Fruit', 'Brocolli': 'Veggies', 'Tomato': 
# 'Veggies', 'Cake': 'Dessert'}

test['type'] = (test.Food.str.split(expand=True)
                         .stack()
                         .map(d_inv)
                         .groupby(level=0)
                         .agg(' '.join))
```

---

```
print(test)

        Food           type
0      Apple Cake  Fruit Dessert
1   Orange Tomato  Fruit Veggies
2  Brocolli Apple  Veggies Fruit
3     Cake Orange  Dessert Fruit
4    Tomato Apple  Veggies Fruit
```

Comment: nice one, i was having trouble inverting the dict but had pretty much the same solution. @OP i'd consider using a single case to account for better string matching.

Comment: df['Food'] = df['Food'].str.lower() would be correct, no? Great Idea, Thanks!

Comment: Yes it would. Glad it helped :) @bismo

Comment: Thank you so much! I have an additional question. After having what you answered, with the two columns I was looking for, how would I go about the following: What if I wanted to make a third column with the counts for the type of food? For example, in my specific df in this question, all values in the third column would be "1 1", but if I had two fruits and a vegetable, I would like the new column to say 2, 1. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see. Note however that this is quite I different question. I'd kindly encourage you to ask a follow-up separate question. Also this could also confuse future readers otherwise. Do ping me when you do so :) @bismo

Comment: @yatu I have asked the new question I have. Thanks!